# How to approach a C++ parser

Tags: c++, parsing, formatting

I am wanting to have a go at a C++ parser for a formatter I am making.

You can obviously open a file and use getline(..) or get(), is this reasonable way of starting things off and then working out a system using vector arrays and hence creating loads of arrays and somehow structuring out and processing what you are doing from there. For example say I wanted to find ever function in a source file, all functions have the common syntax, "(){" once whitespace has been removed, so do you just look for common  delimeters to parse out the sections into arrays. I suppose I will learn as I go.

Or I also assume there are tried and tested ways of doing this, and I would likley just be reinventing the wheel as they say.

Comment: While C is an easy language to parse, its descendant C++ is quite a different story. It's very hard to properly parse C++ code in a standards compliant way. If you don't have any experience with parsing and compiler theory/practice it's going to be extremely hard.

Comment: Instead of writing a C++ parser yourself (which might turn out to be an incredibly hard task), I'd recommend to use an already existing one (e.g. Clang/LLVM), that allows you to provide plugins.

Comment: This is an extremely complicated task. If you want to learn how it's done, you should look at clang. Clang's architecture is made up of smallish libraries that you could use if you want to parse some C++.

Comment: Don't approach it. Use `clang`, it has great API which should suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a language that is quite hard to parse in the first place. So if you want anything other that really trivial C++ code to be "understood" by your parser, you are definitely better off starting with an existing product.

The [Clang frontend library](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#the-frontend-library) would perhaps be a good starting point.

There are also a number of "source to source" conversion examples based on clang. Here's one of them: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/